# Dots on screen - HP Pavilion dv6000

Tags: linux, xorg, hp-pavilion

I have moved to linux (lubuntu) a few months ago on my HP Pavilion dv6000. Since I installed lubuntu my screen has some weird dots on it, making it hard to use. today I switched to xubuntu, thinking it would solve it, but it didn't. So maybe I should switch to a distro which is not related to Ubuntu? Or maybe it is not the problem?

Here's a picture of the problem:

[image: dots on screen]

Comment: IS it in native resolution? Are proper drivers installed?  Try Mint Linux...instead.

Comment: Yes, that’s graphics memory corruption. You might want to try older versions (to get other versions of the graphics driver).

Comment: thank you very much, ill try and update if it worked, you think 12.04 is old enough? @DanielB

Comment: No need to update, the live version should be sufficient to test it. Just verify the error occurs with the current live version.

Comment: @DanielB Do you think switching to newer graphic card will solve it?

Comment: Maybe. Depends on what the error is. But did you try other versions yet? /edit: Also, it’s a notebook? You most likely won’t be able to switch anything.